# Picture-Problem

Tags: cipher, visual

Here is a picture problem, and the task is to replace the question marks. All the information needed should be there. So... try figure it out! [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 23.11  42.52
>  33.13  51.53
>  22.43  31.21
>  42.21  23.43
>  51.31  33.22
>  41.52  12.11
>  53.12  13.41

because:

> the numbers are coordinates. In *ab.cd   ef.gh* next to each other: a,c,e,g show columns, b,d,f,h show rows. Object "ab" is a similar shape to object "cd", color of "ab" corresponds to color of "ef", and color of "cd" corresponds to color of "gh".

Comment: Correct, well done :)